# In Django Todo App how can each user have a distinct set of the task?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am making a to-do app using Django. Currently, the problem I am facing is that no matter which user logs in, the same set of tasks appears, i.e. if a user adds some task for himself, they appear in every other user's to-do list. How can I modify my code so that each user can have a distinct set of tasks?

Here's some of my code:

**`Models`**

```py
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class TodooModel(models.Model):

    fd = models.TextField()
    cr_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import TodooModel

# Create your views here.
   

 def home(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request,"home.html")
        else:
            return redirect("user_login")

    def create(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.method == "POST":
                fdk= request.POST.get("task")
                data = TodooModel(fd=fdk)
                data.save()
            
                return render(request,"create.html",{"msg":"Added Succesfully"})
            else:
            
                return render(request,"create.html")
        else:
            return redirect("user_login")

        
    
    def views(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            data = TodooModel.objects.get()
            return render(request,"views.html",{"data":data})
        else:
            return redirect("user_login")


    def delete(request,id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
       de = TodooModel.objects.get(id=id)
            de.delete()
            return redirect("views")
        else:
            return redirect("user_login")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add new field to the `TodooModel` model,

When you create entry in `TodooModel` add `created_by` paramater.

And while filtering tasks you need to add `created_by=user`.

```
created_by = models.ForiegnKey() # add new field to your model.


data = TodooModel(fd=fdk, created_by=request.user) # in your create method

data = TodooModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user) # in view method
```

**Edit**

Your code should be like,

models,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class TodooModel(models.Model):
    fd = models.TextField()
    cr_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

create method,

```
def create(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            fdk = request.POST.get("task")
            data = TodooModel(fd=fdk, created_by=request.user)
            data.save()

            return render(request, "create.html", {"msg": "Added Succesfully"})
        else:

            return render(request, "create.html")
    else:
        return redirect("user_login")
```

view method,

```
def views(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        data = TodooModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
        return render(request, "views.html", {"data": data})
    else:
        return redirect("user_login")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @KaustubhSawant I have added snippet, check it.